# How can I set plain value (no json) for cookie in Yii2

Tags: php, cookies, yii2

I use this code for set cookie in `Yii2`:

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'googtrans',
    'value' => '//fa',
    'expire' => time()+(60*60*24*365),
]));
```

When I check cookies manager in browser, I see this:

```
378abb4ba4b3ed4bd5fa0918a34e0ba6c4042aecd590d167d76f6a901660d082a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A9%3A%22googtrans%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A4%3A%22%2F%2Ffa%22%3B%7D
```

After decode it I see:

```
378abb4ba4b3ed4bd5fa0918a34e0ba6c4042aecd590d167d76f6a901660d082a:2:{i:0;s:9:"googtrans";i:1;s:4:"//fa";}
```

Seems, `Yii2` convert cookies data to `JSON` format automatically.

But I don't need this, and I want to have a cookie value plain, with `googtrans` name and `//fa` value.
(I know about `$_COOKIE` in PHP core, but I want use Yii)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not **JSON**. it uses PHP's [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) method before hashing it:

```
// retrieved from yii\web\Response::sendCookies()
$value = $cookie->value;
if ($cookie->expire != 1  && isset($validationKey)) {
    $value = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->hashData(serialize([$cookie->name, $value]), $validationKey);
}
setcookie($cookie->name, $value, $cookie->expire, $cookie->path, $cookie->domain, $cookie->secure, $cookie->httpOnly);
```

See full code [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/9d9b63c05a9f641cdd99f3321c7378e0d5b62f5a/framework/web/Response.php#L363-L382).

The thing is whenever [$enableCookieValidation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$enableCookieValidation-detail) is set to true (which is the case by default) Yii will do that to validate the received cookies against tamper.

So you may want to completely disable the built-in Cookie Validation by using those configs:

```
'request' => [
    'enableCookieValidation' => false,
    'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
]
```

But **I DON'T RECOMMEND IT** as there is security reasons to build it that way. To decode the cookie's value anywhere inside the Yii app you can always do it as described in the [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookies):

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->request->cookies;
if (($cookie = $cookies->get('googtrans')) !== null) {
    $googtrans = $cookie->value;
}
```

Otherwise if what you need is client being able to read the real value of some cookie I suggest using `$_COOKIE` instead to directly set/get it as has been also recommended by its creator [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3371).

Comment: Thanks, I write this code and works well: 
`$cookie = Yii::$app->request->cookies['googtrans'];
        $value = $cookie->value;
        if ($cookie->expire != 1  && isset($validationKey)) {
            $value = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->hashData(serialize([$cookie->name, $value]), $validationKey);
        }
        setrawcookie($cookie->name, $value, $cookie->expire, $cookie->path, $cookie->domain, $cookie->secure, $cookie->httpOnly);`
But as you said, don't need to get and validate and overwrite it, so I just use this: `setrawcookie('googtrans', '//fa', time()+(60*60*24*365), '/');`